# Using visitor pattern for checking derived class type?

Tags: c++, inheritance, dynamic-cast, visitor-pattern

I am using the visitor pattern to deal with a lot of different AST problems, which turns out to work really well. For instance, I am using it to check for static type. This works well when looking for the exact type, however it doesn't apply to derived classes. i.e. If we have `Derived` that inherit from `Base`, asking if a `Derived` object is a `Base` fails.

Consider the following C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Base;
class Derived;

class Visitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(Base& object) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Derived& object) = 0;
};

class EmptyVisitor : public Visitor {
public:
    virtual void visit(Base& object) override {}
    virtual void visit(Derived& object) override {}
};

template <class TYPE> class LogicVisitor : public EmptyVisitor {
public:
    LogicVisitor(function<void(TYPE&)> logic) : EmptyVisitor(), logic(logic) {}
    virtual void visit(TYPE& object) override { logic(object); }
private:
    function<void(TYPE&)> logic;
};

class Base {
public:
    virtual void accept(Visitor* visitor) {
        visitor->visit(*this);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    virtual void accept(Visitor* visitor) override {
        visitor->visit(*this);
    }
};

template <class TYPE> bool is_type(shared_ptr<Base> base)
{
    bool is_type = false;
    LogicVisitor<TYPE> logic_visitor([&](TYPE& object) {
        is_type = true;
    });
    base->accept((Visitor*)&logic_visitor);
    return is_type;
}

int main() {
    auto base = make_shared<Base>();
    auto derived = make_shared<Derived>();
    cout << "is_type<Base>(base) = " << (is_type<Base>(base) ? "true" : "false") << endl;
    cout << "is_type<Derived>(base) = " << (is_type<Derived>(base) ? "true" : "false") << endl;
    cout << "is_type<Base>(derived) = " << (is_type<Base>(derived) ? "true" : "false") << endl;
    cout << "is_type<Derived>(derived) = " << (is_type<Derived>(derived) ? "true" : "false") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs *as expected* the following result:

```
is_type<Base>(base) = true
is_type<Derived>(base) = false
is_type<Base>(derived) = false
is_type<Derived>(derived) = true
```

While this is great to retrieve the static type of an object, how can this be fixed if I wanted `is_type<Base>(derived)` to return `true` instead of `false` so that I can effectively check class inheritance? Is this possible in C++?

Comment: Why do you need all this virtual mesh if you can simply use `std::is_base_of`?

Comment: Well I wasn't aware of `std::is_base_of`, that looks very useful indeed, but then the question is, does this function require RTTI?

Comment: @Deathicon No. It's a type trait, which gets evaluated at compile time.

Comment: Did you try to step through your code with a debugger? If you did - the source of the issue you are facing would be obvious to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. The reason why is overload resolution (and your design pattern). Every visitor has two overloads, one for `Base&` and the second one for `Derived&`. `LogicVisitor` overrides the function with the type passed as template parameter, so for `Base` it will override `void visit(Base&)`.

You want it to override `void visit(Derived&)` for `Base` instead (or additionally). But that would require the visitor to find every class that derives from `Base`, which is not possible at the moment.

You can use `std::is_base_of` instead:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr bool is_type(std::shared_ptr<U>) {
    return std::is_base_of_v<std::decay_t<T>, std::decay_t<U>>;
}
```

Comment: Yes using `std::is_base_of` is what I should have used. The question isn't relevant anymore when you know that this functionality exist. Thanks!